# useEffect shows double result after back button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a program where I use useeffect to get products I have in my database. I use useeffect with an empty array as a dependency, so the data only loads when the component is rendered. The problem is that if I change the page and right after use the browser's back button, the component shows double the products.

**code**

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  }, []);
```

Comment: If you refresh multiple times page does product increase always?

Comment: you may attach `fetchProducts` code, it probably just pushing the results without clearing the array before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you `dispatch` a redux action, it seems that you store the fetched products on `redux`. The redux state is not affected by route changes and is stored throughout the app until cleaned manually.

So what you can do is, you can define another action named `cleanUpProducts` in your reducer and within this function, you can clean up stored products in the redux store.

After that, you can dispatch this action in `return` function of your `useEffect` (the equivalent of `componentWillUnmount`) hook like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
    return () => {
        dispatch(cleanUpProducts());
    }
}, []);
```